# OutOfBounds when working with objects in an array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

When I am creating an array of `Example` objects, I call something like `initializeArray();` I use a simple nested for loop to traverse through the array and then assign new objects with values to each index of the array using `exampleArr[i][j] = new Example(false, false, false, 0);` however, calling this gives me an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException:0` at the line above.

I am assuming that I am instantiating the new object incorrectly, as this also happens in another method which is supposed to display all of the `Example` objects in the array. However, I will post the nested loop I am using in case there is something that i've done wrong that I can't see.

```
public void initializeArray(){
    for(int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < getColumns(); j++){
             tileArr[i][j] = new Tile(false, false, false, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

//Declaration of rows and columns

```
    private int rows; 
    private int columns; 
    Tile[][] tileArr = new Tile[rows][columns]; 
public void setRows(int r)
{   
 rows = r; 
} 
 public void setColumns(int c)
 { 
     //various setters and getters for the array 
  columns = c; 
 } 
public int getRows()
{ 

  System.out.print(rows); 
  return rows; 
} 
public int getColumns()
{ 
  System.out.print(columns); 
  return columns; 
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help! The problem has been solved.

Comment: `tileArr` must has a compatible size, i.e. it must be created with something like `Tile[] tileArr = new TileArr[n][m];`

Comment: You are initializing individual element but have not allocated memory for the array or declared size is less than your iteration count.

Comment: Can you please post your declaration. Because if I assume that you have not allocated memory then it should have been `NullPointerException`. Please clear the clouds by posting variable declaration

Comment: Where have you called setters for row and column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `tileArr` at the top but do not initialize.

```
Tile[][] tileArr;
```

Then initialize your array before your `for` loop in the `initializeArray()` (This is assuming your `rows` and `columns` is set. You can add logic to check this as well).

```
tileArr = new Tile[getRows()][getColumns()];
tileArr = new Tile[rows][columns]; //Do this instead if you don't want the print statements to be called
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear, that's one of my instance variables at the top of the class.

Comment: @Bert can you show us how you initialized it then at the top?

Comment: and also please add the implementations of getRows() and getColumns() methods in case there might be some problem with them

Comment: `private int rows;    
 private int columns;    
 Tile[][] tileArr = new Tile[rows][columns];    

 public void setRows(int r){
  rows = r;
 }
 public void setColumns(int c){  //various setters and getters for the array
  columns = c;
 }
 public int getRows(){
  System.out.print(rows);
  return rows;
  
 }
 public int getColumns(){
  System.out.print(columns);
  return columns;
 }`

Comment: @gonzo, sorry It's not letting me format it for some reason.

Comment: When you initialize `tileArr` both `rows` and `columns` are `0`. You should probably declare `tileArr` at the top like you are currently doing but don't initialize until you have `rows` and `columns` set.

Comment: @Bert also just edit your original question and put all of that code in there.  Thanks. :)

Comment: It works, thank you! Now I just need to figure out my toString method, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bert Feel free to accept the answer. Glad i was able to help. :)

Comment: @gonzo, thanks again, I accepted the answer, after i found the button lol.

Answer (score 0):

As @gonzo said you have got to initialize your array to allocate enough memory for all the positions you are going to be using.

```
Tile[][] tileArr;

public void initializeArray(){
       Tile[][] tileArr = new Tile[getRows()][getColumns()];
       for(int i = 0; i < getRows(); i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < getColumns(); j++){
                tileArr[i][j] = new Tile(false, false, false, 0);
           }
       }
       return titleArr;
}

//...wherever you want it
this.tileArray = this.initializeArray()
```

But there are cases when you don't know how big this array may be. For those cases you should be using `List<Tile>` type  like `LinkedList<Tile>` or `ArrayList<Tile>` so that you don't need to allocate space for every new position to use.

Comment: If it was the problem of allocating memory, shouldn't it throw NPE

Comment: @SacJn Nope because he is trying to access a position that doesn't exist in the array before even trying to use it

Comment: I tried running the code for `int x[][]=null`. It throws NPE

Comment: @SacJn try this `String [][] tileArr = new String[1][1]; System.out.println(tileArr[1][2]);`

Comment: In your comment, you have allocated memory definitely but not enough. So it won't . But what your statement says **you have got to initialize your array to allocate space for its positions** is ambiguous then. Rather you can specify it for sufficient memory. Anyway there was just misunderstanding or miss of words so lets end it here